# Cannot deploy nest.js project to Google Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nestjs

NestJs uses ES6, ES7 and ES8, but Firebase Functions is stuck at Node v.6.11.

I tried to write a webpack config file w/ babel to transpile both my files and the node_modules to node v6.11 but I'm not able to complete the deploy due to a syntax error caused by an async function in the @nestjs/common/interceptors/file-fields.interceptor.js file.

```
⚠  functions[api]: Deployment error.
Function load error: Code in file dist/index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: /user_code/node_modules/@nestjs/common/interceptors/file-fields.interceptor.js:10
        async intercept(context, call$) {
              ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@nestjs/common/interceptors/index.js:6:10)
```

Here's my webpack.config.js file:

```
'use strict';
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/server.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'this'
    },
    target: 'node',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    { 
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                [
                                    '@babel/preset-env',
                                    {
                                        "targets": {
                                        "node": "6.11.1"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    '@babel/stage-0'
                                ]
                            ],
                            plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator')]
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        loader: 'ts-loader',
                        options: {
                            transpileOnly: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    { 
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                [
                                    '@babel/preset-env',
                                    {
                                        "targets": {
                                        "node": "6.11.1"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    '@babel/stage-0'
                                ]
                            ],
                            plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator')]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ]
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()]
};
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6", "es2015.promise"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "spec/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong but can you try deploying to the Node 8 beta runtime and see if the issue persists? (change your babel and typescript config to target it)

Comment: It works on node 8. The problem is transpiling to node v6 :/
If you bootstrap a simple helloworld app using the latest version of nestjs and then try to deploy to Firebase cloud, you'll see the error on deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly 3 days ago (after Google Cloud’s Next conf) Google just announced the new Node 8 runtime and Firebase Cloud Functions 2.0.0 and Firebase tools to 4.0.0.

Here’s what you need to do to get on the Node 8 train:

1. Upgrade your `firebase-functions version` to 2.0.0
2. Upgrade `firebase-tools` to 4.0.0
3. Add "engines": `{ “node": “8” }` to your `/functions/package.json`

More deets here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version

Answer (score -1):

Node 6 won't run any code using the `async` keyword as it [doesn't support](https://node.green/) async functions from ES2017.

I'd recommend trying to use TypeScript for the transpilation of your code, using `es6` as a `target` in your `tsconfig.json`. It should transpile async functions. Please keep in mind that you might have to load specific polyfills depending on your needs. And you're probably aware of this detail but NestJS specifies Node 8.9+, as documented [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide):

> We follow the Node.js release schedule which recently moved to 8.x as an active LTS version. Therefore, Nest 5 supports >= 8.9.0 as the lowest version now. This shift gaves us sustainable performance boosts thanks to the es2017 target of the TypeScript compilation.

Comment: I'm already using ts-loader (with es6 as the target) to transpile typescript files + babel 7 w/ preset-env that targets node v6.